# Fetch data from multiple categories

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 3 tables in my database the structure is

```
 advertisement 
 +--+-----+------------+
 |id|name |description | 
 +--+-----+------------+
 | 1| Name| some text  |
 +--+-----+------------+


Categories
+---+-------------+
|id |category_name|
+---+-------------+ 
|2  |category 1   | 
|3  |category 2   | 
|4  |category 3   | 
+---+-------------+
```

and the last table is where to store my advertisement, i want to make multiple categories choise the table structure is

```
+---------+------+
|advert_id|cat_id|
+---------+------+
|    1    |   2  |
|    1    |   3  |
+---------+------+
```

i insert the data to my database but i cant fetch the data for editing in feature like this

```
<select>
<select name="cat[]" multiple>
<option value="id" selected>Category 2</option>
<option value="id" selected>Category 3</option>
<option value="id" selected>Category 3</option>
</select>
```

i write this code by it's show only one selected category

```
<?php
function advert_select($advert_id){
    $data = array();
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM `advert_to_area` WHERE `advert_id`=$advert_id");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $data[] = array(
        'area_id'   => $row['area_id']
        );

    }   
    return $data;
}

function get_advert_cat(){
    $data = array();
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM `areas`");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $data[] = array(
        'id'        => $row['id'],
        'name'      => $row['area_name']
        );
    }
    return $data;
}
?>
<?php
echo '<select name="areas[]" multiple>';
$data = advert_select($advert_data['id']);
$areas = get_advert_cat();
foreach($data as $d){
    $area_id = $d['area_id'];

}
foreach ($areas as $area){

    if($area['id']==$area_id){
        echo '<option value="' . $area['id'] .'" selected>' . $area['name'] . '</option>';
    }else{
        echo '<option value="' . $area['id'] .'" >' . $area['name'] . '</option>';
    }
}

echo "</select>";
?>
```

can you tell me please what i do wrong or what can i do to show like the example that i give. Thanks

Comment: please brother your self in formatting code post properly

Comment: $cat=array(); 
$cat=$_post['cat'];

Comment: `foreach($data as $d){$area_id=$d['area_id'];}` so `$area_id` ends up in one single value, and so no matter how many categories your ad in, the `<select>` will only select one.

Comment: i found the way with joining the tables in mysql

Comment: How about using jQuery with AJAX (this way you get what should be marked with AJAX and execute with jQuery) or checkbox in order to have the multiple items selected ? I don't think you can set multiple items by default with just HTML

Comment: First of all, think object oriented. Maybe you've already listened a thing about MVC. My humble suggestion is for you to take a first look [here](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2005/09/15/mvc_intro.html) and [there](http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should work.

```
<?php
echo '<select name="areas[]" multiple>';
$data = advert_select($advert_data['id']);
$areas = get_advert_cat();
$area_id = array();
foreach($data as $d){
    $area_id[] = $d['area_id'];

}
foreach ($areas as $area){

    if(in_array($area['id'],$area_id)){
        echo '<option value="' . $area['id'] .'" selected>' . $area['name'] . '</option>';
    }else{
        echo '<option value="' . $area['id'] .'" >' . $area['name'] . '</option>';
    }
}

echo "</select>";
?>
```